# How to Call Php using the button html?

Tags: php, html, button

Can anyone tell me how to call a php using the button in html. I want my on/off button (which is in my html page) to call php and register it to my database when the button is on/off. I am new to this so not sure if it's possible and how to do it. some help will be very helpful. thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
h1 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin-right:60px;
}
</style>
    <title> Washing Machine Control System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BK.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MachineButtons.css"/>
</head>

<body bgcolor = "Black"> 
<h1>Machine Controller</h1> 

    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <div id="icons"><img src="D:\Year 4 (Sem1&2)\Mobile Technologies\Coursework\Website\WM1.jpg"  alt="Machine One" style="width:150px;height:228px;"/></a></div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
            <span class="switch-label" data-on="M1 On" data-off="M1 Off"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
        </label>
    <div id="icons2"><img src="D:\Year 4 (Sem1&2)\Mobile Technologies\Coursework\Website\WM2.jpg" alt="Machine Two" style="width:150px;height:228px;"/></a></div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
            <span class="switch-label" data-on="M2 On" data-off="M2 Off"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
        </label>
    <div id="icons4"><img src="D:\Year 4 (Sem1&2)\Mobile Technologies\Coursework\Website\WM3.jpg"  alt="Machine Three" style="width:150px;height:228px;"/></a></div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
            <span class="switch-label" data-on="M3 On" data-off="M3 Off"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
        </label>
    <div id="icons3"><img src="D:\Year 4 (Sem1&2)\Mobile Technologies\Coursework\Website\WM4.jpg" alt="Machine Four" style="width:150px;height:228px;"/></a></div>
        <label class="switch">
            <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
            <span class="switch-label" data-on="M4 On" data-off="M4 Off"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
        </label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use a conditional statement

Comment: Start by looking up the HTML tag `<form>` and then the [PHP Dealing with Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can not execute PHP functions on trigger of browser events.

Either you need to use the AJAX or more easy, you can just create two separate files - one containing the code for ON and one for OFF and link them to the on and off buttons using the anchor tag. Whenever the user will click a button, respective page will be opened, status will be updated in the database and the user will be redirected to the original page.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to make a request to your PHP. How I usually handle this kind of stuff (with jQuery) is create a button:

```
<button id="button">ON/OFF</button>
```

Then create your JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $.get("update.php?set=1");
    });
});
```

Then update.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['set'])) { // Is ?set= available?
        $query = "UPDATE tablename SET value = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['set']) . "'"; // Update `tablename` and set the colum value to the value of ?set=#VALUE#
        $run = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

**Note that this example ONLY sets it to 1, so you either need to make 2 buttons to for ON/OFF, or make it more complicated by checking what value its on now, and then invert it.**